# using react-router-dom , styled-components css is not loading properly

Tags: reactjs, electron, react-router-dom, styled-components

> App.js

```
const App = (props) => {     

        return (
            <div>
               <HashRouter>                             
                    <Route path='/' exact component={Main} />
                    <Route path='/settings' exact component={Settings} />
              </HashRouter>                  
            </div>
            )    
}
```

**Scenario I :**
Navigating to 'Settings' page an navigating back to Main page using `history.push()`

This is how the page appears

[image]

**Scenario II :**
Refreshing the Setting page and then moving back to Main Page
This is how the page appears[image]

[image]

```
react: 17.0.1
react-dom: 17.0.1
react-router-dom: 5.2.0
styled-components: 5.2.1
electron: 10.2.0
```

Comment: I've been experiencing something similar for quite some time, 6 months at least. It cropped up after chasing a warning in the browser that led me to update react router dom